# How to tell if a video is HDR or not in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, avassetexportsession

I need to detect if a video is HDR or not and on that basis I want to make a decision. I am using `AVKit`.
Is there any way to tell the difference.
Thanks.

Comment: To get the best support here you should always show some code you tried yourself.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple and precise:

```
var isHdrVideo = false
    let pVideoTrack = AVAsset(url: URL(fileURLWithPath: assetURL!))
    if #available(iOS 14.0, *) {
        let tracks = pVideoTrack.tracks(withMediaCharacteristic: .containsHDRVideo)
        for track in tracks{
            isHdrVideo = track.hasMediaCharacteristic(.containsHDRVideo)
            if(isHdrVideo){
                break
            }
        }
    }
```